# addConstraint method being called on unrelated view object

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint

I have been reading some code online and this is how its setup -

A `scrollContainerView` as a subview inside my `view`.

A `scrollView` as a subview inside `scrollContainerView`.

```
[self.view addConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[scrollView]|"options:0 metrics:nil views:viewDictionary]]
```

Now as per the visual format, the `scrollView` is getting getting vertically pinned on top and bottom edge to its superview, the superview being `scrollContainerView`.

**QN 1 -**

I am confused as to why the resultant constraint is being added to `self.view` and not the `scrollview`. Why is the constraint added to self.view when its not related to the constraint being added.

**QN 2 -**

Suppose I have a a superview named `viewOuter` and its subview named `viewInner`. Then is there any difference between -

```
[viewOuter addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:viewInner attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:viewOuter attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]]
```

and

```
[viewInner addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:viewInner attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:viewOuter attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constraints have to be added to a view which is an ancestor of all of the views involved in the constraints, where a view is considered to be an "ancestor" of itself. They don't have to be added to the **closest** ancestor, though that's how it's most commonly done.

So, for your first question, it's just how the person who wrote that code decided to do it. Not clear *why* they made that decision.

For your second question, only the first form is allowed. The second is invalid because the receiver is not an ancestor of all of the views involved in the constraint.

Lastly, I'll just say that in iOS 8.0 or later, you can simply set the `active` property on a constraint and it will automatically add or remove itself from the relevant view. Similarly, you can do `[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:constraints]` and `[NSLayoutConstraint deactivateConstraints:constraints]` to add or remove constraints in bulk without having to figure out which views they should be added to or removed from.